# Executing React method 3 times and performing an action on the 3rd try

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have a call to an endpoint to get some resources, the backend guy suggested to try the call 3 times with a 5 seconds delay between each call. so I created the function below...

```
const timeout = delay => {
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay))
}

const retry = useRef(0)

const fetchAPIResource = useCallback(
    async () =>
      await getStatus(transactionID)
        .then(async res => {
          if (res?.status === 204) {
            await timeout(5000)
            fetchAPIResource()
          }
          if (!res?.data?.receipt_is_settled && retry.current !== 3) {
            await timeout(5000)
            fetchAPIResource()
            retry.current += 1
          }
          if (res?.data?.receipt_is_settled) {
            setStatus('accepted')
            setShow(false)
          }
          if (!res?.data?.receipt_is_settled && retry.current === 3) {
            setStatus('declined')
            setShow(false)
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          toast.error(error?.errors?.description || error?.description)
          setStatus('declined')
        }),
    [],
  )
```

My issue now is for a split second while the last call is executing, this condition `(!res?.data?.receipt_is_settled && retry.current === 3)` is true and so the error screen shows before the success screen, I need help making this better so I get the error screen or success screen only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...this condition (!res?.data?.receipt_is_settled && retry.current === 3) is true and so the error screen shows before the success screen...

That tells me you're using `retry.current` as part of your rendering logic. Because it's not in state (or purely derived from state), you shouldn't be doing that.

I would make the error state an explicit state, and make the retry counter something local to the `useCallback` callback. No reason for that information to be available outside the code handling the retry logic.

It also seems odd to retry a *successful* (status = 200) request.

Also note that mixing `async`/`await` with `.then`/`.catch` makes for difficult-to-follow code, and

I tried to rework the code to give an example of how you might do it, but the code raises a lot of questions:

- Can `res` really be nullish?
- When getting a `status` other than `204`, can `res.data` really be nullish?
- When there's an error, can `error` really be nullish?
- Why do some things count as retries but other things don't?
- Why isn't the counter reset anywhere?

So here's my take, making the assumptions that:

1. Retrying successful operations is not necessary.
2. All of the branches where you did the timeout and retry should count as retries.
3. Any status other than 200 or 204 is a failure we shouldn't retry

```
const fetchAPIResource = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
        for (let retries = 0; retries < 3; ++retries) {
            const res = await getStatus();
            if (res.status === 200 && res.data.receipt_is_settled) {
                // All good
                setStatus("accepted");
                setShow(false);
                return;
            }
            if (res.status !== 200 && res.status !== 204) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error ${res.status}`);
            }
            // Retry
            await timeout(5000);
        }
        // Out of retries
        setStatus("declined");
        setShow(false);
    } catch (error) {
        // *** Can `error` really be nullish?
        // *** Shouldn't there be a default if both of the below are `undefined`?
        toast.error(error?.errors?.description || error?.description);
        setStatus("declined");
        // *** Shouldn't there be a `setShow(false);` here?
    }
}, []);
```

Not shown in the above: The process should probably be cancelled if the component is unmounted sometime during those up-to-15 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, the reason for retrying when I get the 204 is because the BE guy sends that status to lets us know to retry the request, also when the response is 200 but the receipt_is_settled is false, he suggested retrying 3 more times just to be sure and if we still get the same response then we move forward, his reason, he says is because of the way the API is set up, they have to perform a bunce of requests too on their end so it takes time to validate the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

javascript runs the code by order, in your code, you put

```
if (!res?.data?.receipt_is_settled && retry.current !== 3) {
            await timeout(5000)
            fetchAPIResource()
            retry.current += 1
          }
```

before

```
if (!res?.data?.receipt_is_settled && retry.current === 3) {
            setStatus('declined')
            setShow(false)
          }
```

so the condition `retry.current === 3` will always true after the secod trial. The solution for this is that you can try to put this code:

```
if (!res?.data?.receipt_is_settled && retry.current === 3) {
            setStatus('declined')
            setShow(false)
          }
```

above or before

```
if (!res?.data?.receipt_is_settled && retry.current !== 3) {
            await timeout(5000)
            fetchAPIResource()
            retry.current += 1
          }
```